# Wildcard subdomain picks up www.domain.com as a sub domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

Sorry if my question title may be misleading, it was hard to word it out. I just set up wildcard subdomains with apache and it works flawlessly however, when accessing my main domain with `www` I get a 404 because it's treating `www` as a subdomain.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName wildcard.domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.com
VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/subdomains/%1"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory /var/www/html/>
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is in my apache configuration on my server. When I visit (any).domain.com it will show to contents of `/var/www/subdomains/(any)`. Now that works however, when visiting `www.domain.com` it goes to 404 as (www) doesn't exist in `/var/www/subdomains/`. I want to ignore `www` in the urls.

To sum it all up

- `domain.com` leads to my root as intended
- `www.domain.com` leads to a 404 not found `/`

I would also like to redirect all subdomains that lead to 404s back to root.

Comment: Place second virtual host onto upper position and check the behavior. Missed `</VirtualHost>`. By default it must choose the v.host with www.domain.com.

Comment: There was a mistake with the editor, there you go.

Comment: Alright, switched the positions of the virtual hosts and it worked. Thanks

Comment: I am facing something similar. When I use www..example.com it will load the website from the wildcard subdomain. If you don't use the www then it will pick the data from the parent domain that is correct example.com. 

So in case anyone go with www I want to force redirect it to https.example.com

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by placing the wildcard virtual host as the last virtual host.